# Custom Status of Custom Post type need to EXCLUDE from Taxonomy pages

Tags: customization, terms, post-status

I have 400 custom post type posts saved as DRAFT which are no longer in use but it can be in future, So for SEO purpose i want now to have all those posts accessible with direct URL but not showing on any term/taxonomy/archive pages. So i need to EXCLUDE it from terms pages because as soon as i change status they start displaying in existing terms pages along with other published posts.

I used following :

`register_post_status( 'holiday', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Holiday', 'post' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Holiday(%s)', 'Holiday(%s)' ),`

I do not know if its correct way or not but on term page i have :

`if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();`

I changed this to :

`$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post_type',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $term->slug,
        )
    ),
);`

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($the_query->have_posts()):
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

Previous scenario : 150 published, 400 Draft ( page load is fine, if i publish 100 more then archive/term pages goes down)
Current Scenario : 150 published, 400 Holiday status and on archive,term pages shows only published one by using above code but page goes down, so i am confused if query is fetching all public posts (including publish + holiday)and then only showing published one? It gives memory consumed error so i am sure its only because it can not show so many posts on archive page.

Question :
1) How to exclude new custom post type posts with custom status from term/archive pages (best way to do)